# Facing some questions regarding my energy meter project

Tags: microcontroller, power, power-electronics, meter

I am working on my minor project in college and am facing a dilemma/problem with it.

**Project Description:**
I am working with an energy meter and am trying to make it smart (in the same way as many exist today). I want to extract data from the meter, collect it through a board such as Raspberry Pi/[Intel Edison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Edison) or using any other microcontroller. There are other things to be done with this data, but I face the problem with extraction of data from the meter.

There are two types of energy meter that I was able to find for this project:

1. Use the conventional ones with no port connectivity like the one below. These are very cheap, like US$5. Only voltage and energy consumption is displayed.

[image]

2. Then, there are others which have dedicated ports for communication using [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485)/RS-232 or may be [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus). These are expensive, but they give all sorts of data and can easily be communicated with to extract the data.

For example,

[image]

Now, I demand in my project that it should be feasible. There is no point in using a US$20-US$25 energy meter. I would love to know in what way we can take the data from the conventional energy meters which are not having any dedicated ports for this purpose. Do we need to make any external hardware to do so or if nothing, then are there any energy meters available which have the connectivity port and are cheap as well?

Comment: How about building your own meter vs buying one?  At the simplest you could assume a constant voltage and just measure the current.

Comment: If it has a rotating disk you can place a photo sensor that sensds pulse when the white spot on disk is sensed.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Actually we thought of that only but we have shortage of time .@Marko your suggestion is a good one, but please try anything with a digital one.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way would be to buy an energy meter with dedicated serial interface and connect it to your Raspberry-Pi. As you said, you will get a lot more information with a digital meter than from an analog one. But they are also the most expensive ones.

Some cheaper meter don't have a serial interface but a so called S0 interface. 
[image]

This is basically an open-collector digital output which closes about 1000 times per kWh (depending on your meter). With an external pull-up resistor, you get nice pulses which you could read with your Raspberry-Pi and an GPIO library with interrupts. You can use [pigpiod](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) to generate interrupts and measure the time-interval between two consecutive pulses. With this, you can calculate the instantaneous power consumption.

If you have an analog meter with dial pointers you could try to read those pointers with some kind of short range distance sensor like [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/466) to generate pulses every revolution.

Comment: And do you know the model/manufacturer of such devices having SO interface.

Comment: EAC, Finder, ABB, for example see here [Ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=din%20rail%20watt%20meter&_fscr=1), and for a reference see [Raspberry Pi Power Monitor](http://www.ramge.de/powermonitor/doku.php?id=pulse_meter) Google is your friend

Answer (score 1):

There are convectional electromechanical meters used throughout in India.
There design is rather simple having a `Rotating disk or a ring` where the no. of revolution  per second are proportional to the amount of power passing through the meter.[image]

This is a diagram showing the basic principle of the meter, electromechanical induction causes the disk to rotate.

***These disc usually have a red/black paint describing the beginning or initial zero***
disassemble the meter take the disc out make the red paint a lot darker using a **black paint**, try to increase its width if possible.
[image: Meter]

Now put a combination of high intensity LED and a LDR sense to sense the reflection from the rotating disc,with a perfect combination of these 2 you can sense the occurrence of mark portion(`again you will need to work on these, to get things right`). when the marked portion appears it means one complete round.Define constraints in your code, and to be perfectly accurate add some delay as the strip is long.

Hence you can now easily calculate the power as you know the revolution.Best of Luck.